# ¿Cómo generar líneas de texto separadas en una imagen con opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He intentado escribir en una imagen líneas por separado. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código se abre un archivo de texto `Lista.txt` para lectura se lee el contenido y al pasar esas líneas a un documento jpg pone una tras otra, simplemente me gustaría saber si se puede usar algún tipo de /n.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Hoja.jpg')

registro = open("Log.txt", "r")
texto = registro.readlines()
ubicacion = (86,950)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
tamañoLetra = 6
colorLetra = (0,0,0)
grosorLetra = 2

y0, dy = 500, 10
for i, line in enumerate(('\n').join(texto)):
y = y0 + i*dy
cv2.putText(img, line, (50, y ), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 5[!, 20)
cv2.imwrite('Hoja lista.jpg', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Puedes usar `registro.readlines()` para obtener una lista de cadenas, una por cada línea, y después iterar sobre esa lista para pintarlas una a una (tendrás que ir variando la posición Y)

Comment: A la hora de ejecutar el código me da error en la zona que introduce el texto en la imagen. He intentado varias soluciones y no he conseguido nada. El error dice esto "Can't convert object to 'str' for 'text'"

Comment: ¿Qué código es el que dices que te está dando error? Puedes pulsar "Editar" en tu pregunta y añadir más información. ¿No estarás pasándole a `putText()` directamente lo que te devuelve `.readlines()`, no? Eso es una lista, no una cadena, tendrías que iterar por ella como te dije. (Mira por ejemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647540/1264820))

Comment: Me da error en el cv2.putText como a la persona del link que has pasado, he intentado con la solución que le dicen pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Pongo una captura.

Comment: Estas usando mal el `join`, este es un método de los strings. Lo correcto sería hacer `"\n".join(texto)`

Comment: Ahora parece que al cambiar el join funciona solo que con el texto del link lo ecribe todo hacia abajo.

Comment: Por lo que describes, parece que `texto` no es una lista, sino una cadena. Al iterar por la cadena obtienes las letras separadas, razón por la que sale una debajo de otra. Tienes que hacer que `texto` sea una lista (de cadenas, cada una una línea del fichero), para lo que debes leerlo así: `texto = registro.readlines()`

Comment: He vuelto a cambiar esto y nada, no se que puede ser lo que hace que escriba en vertical y todo junto. He dejado el código actual y el resultado.

Comment: En el enumerate solo debes poner la variable texto. Así `for i, line in enumerate(texto):`

Comment: Al cambiarlo me dió error en la linea de putText y al hacer unos cambios sigue igual. No he podido arreglarlo

Answer (score 1):

no sé si estoy en lo correcto de lo que buscas, así que pongo un ejemplo:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Hoja.jpg')

with open("Log.txt") as archivo:
    texto = archivo.readlines()
```

uso with porque ya incluye el cerrar el archivo y el modo 'r' viene por defecto así que es una redundancia.

```
x,y = 10,10
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
tamañoLetra = 1
colorLetra = (0,0,0)
grosorLetra = 1
```

cambié las coordenadas, el tamaño y el grosor para que pruebes y porque también desconozco el tamaño de la imagen.

```
for j in range(len(texto)):
    y+=30
    cv2.putText(img,texto[j][:-1],(x,y),font,tamañoLetra,colorLetra,grosorLetra)
```

con esto recorro el largo de la lista y escribo el texto aumentando la posición de "y" ,así quedan una por debajo de la otra

```
cv2.imwrite('hoja_lista.jpg',img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Omití el wait porque le pusiste valor de 0 así que es innecesario.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto. Queda un interrogante al final, pero por lo que he visto creo que no se puede quitar. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @MarioCuenca ahhh, si se puede quitar es simple: ahora modifico el código, es simplemente hacer un slice

Comment: De nuevo muchísimas gracias.